# Configuring values of combobox in a tablelist using tablelist wrapper in python

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter, tcl

Basically my problem is in configuring a combobox in a tablelist written in python (not tcl directly). I have prepared an example that could demonstrate the problem, but before that lets see the required steps to run it:

1. Copy the tablelist wrapper from [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TableListWrapper) and save it as 'tablelist.py', then put it at the example code directory.
2. Download "tklib-0.5" from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcllib/files/) and copy "tablelist" directory from "modules" directory to the directory of example code.

Here it is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tablelist import TableList

class Window (Frame):
    def __init__(self):
#       frame
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
#       tablelist
        self.tableList = TableList(self,
                                    columns = (0, "Parity"),
                                    editstartcommand=self.editStartCmd
                                    )
        self.tableList.grid()
#       configure column #0 
        self.tableList.columnconfigure(0, editable="yes", editwindow="ttk::combobox")
#       insert an item 
        self.tableList.insert(END,('Even'))

    def editStartCmd(self, table, row, col, text):
#
#       must configure "values" option of Combobox here! 
#
        return

def main():
    Window().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you would see it results in a single column/cell window with an initial value (Even). By clicking on the cell the combobox will appear (because of using "editstartcommand") and it doesn't have any values (None). I know for editing cell's widgets one has to use "editwinpath" command to get pathname of temporary widget, but the method just returns a string of the address referring to combobox widget that is not callable.

I'd appreciate any help or possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a bit weird that I'm responding to my own question, but I'm hopeful that it could be useful to others in the future. After reading tablelist scripts and examples in TCL, I was able to find my answer. The answer has two different parts, one is related to the wrapper (tablelist wrapper in python that you can find it [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TableListWrapper)), and the other one resides in my example code. First of all the wrapper needs to be modified to include widgets' pathnames in its "configure" method of "TableList" class. Here it is the modified version:

```
def configure(self, pathname, cnf={}, **kw):
    """Queries or modifies the configuration options of the 
    widget.  

    If no option is specified, the command returns a list 
    describing all of the available options for def (see 
    Tk_ConfigureInfo for information on the format of this list).  
    If option is specified with no value, then the command 
    returns a list describing the one named option (this list 
    will be identical to the corresponding sublist of the value 
    returned if no option is specified).  If one or more 
    option-value pairs are specified, then the command modifies
    the given widget option(s) to have the given value(s); in 
    this case the return value is an empty string.  option may 
    have any of the values accepted by the tablelist::tablelist 
    command.
    """
    return self.tk.call((pathname, "configure") +
                 self._options(cnf, kw))
```

Second and last part is the obligation that the "editstartcommand" (in case of my example code "editStartCmd" method) has to return its "text" variable at the end of it. This trick would prevent entries from turning to "None" as you click on them. The correct form of example code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tablelist import TableList

class Window (Frame):
    def __init__(self):
#       frame
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
#       tablelist
        self.tableList = TableList(self,
                                    columns = (0, "Parity"),
                                    editstartcommand=self.editStartCmd
                                    )
        self.tableList.grid()
#       configure column #0 
        self.tableList.columnconfigure(0, editable="yes", editwindow="ttk::combobox")
#       insert an item 
        self.tableList.insert(END,('Even'))

    def editStartCmd(self, table, row, col, text):
#
#       must configure "values" option of Combobox here! 
#
        pathname = self.tableList.editwinpath()
        self.tableList.configure(pathname, values=('Even','Odd'))
        return text

def main():
    Window().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That's it and I hope it was clear enough.