# Doubts about checking if button is already displayed and making a list of radio buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two questions regarding tkinter that I cant seem to find the answer too.

1) I currently have 2 radio buttons. I have programmed them in such a way that when one of them is clicked another definition is called and that creates a regular button on the screen. Now my problem is, if the user toggles between the both radio buttons, each time a new button will be created (instead of just having 1 the first time he toggles the options). Is there any way I can stop the extra buttons from being created if one already exsists?

2) Is there a widget that can easily be used to create check box lists?

EDIT: Sorry, I meant check box list not radio button list.

Comment: What do you mean by radio button lists? Multiple radio buttons or..?

Comment: @Lafexlos I mean something similar to a treeView widget, except each row has a check box.

Comment: tcl/tk has a tablelist for this. I thinkTkinter has something like that.Look at it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105298/configuring-values-of-combobox-in-a-tablelist-using-tablelist-wrapper-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1> Define you button outside the eventHandler of the radiobutton. 
inside the event handler only grid/pack it,whenever the radiobutton is pressed. In this way the button will not be defined multiple times.

N.B. Use fix row & column with the grid if you need.